# Dynamic form on website

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms

Hi I'm trying to show a form when the edit button is pressed and then once the save button for the form is pressed I'd like to edit my database and show the new information. I need to do this without refreshing the page as well. I'm new to jquery but below is what I've written so far, however, the event.preventDefault(); function isn't working for some reason and the forms action is run. Any help as to why my code is failing would be greatly appreciated thanks!

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<!-- Irrelevant scripts from the site go here -->
</head>
<body>
<!-- Lots of other code from the site is here -->
<div id="jqueryFunction"></div>
<script text="text/javascript">
    function checkEdit(ID){
        //Check the fields make sure they're not empty
        return true;
    }
</script>
<script text="text/javascript">
    function editV(ID, titleOld, descOld){
        document.getElementById("divForm" + ID).innerHTML = 
        "<form name=\"editDiv" + ID + "\" id=\"editDiv" + ID + "\" onsubmit=\"return checkEdit(" + ID + ");\" action=\"editvid.php\" method=\"POST\">" +
        "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"divID\" id=\"divID\" value=\"" + ID + "\"/>" +
        "<input type=\"text\" name=\"titleNew" + ID + "\" id=\"titleNew" + ID + "\" value=\"" + titleOld + "\"/><br>" +
        "<textarea name=\"descNew" + ID + "\" id=\"descNew" + ID + "\">" + descOld + "</textarea><br>" +
        "<input type=\"submit\" value=\"Save\" class=\"alt_btn\">" +
        "</form>";
        document.getElementById("jqueryFunction").innerHTML = 
        "<script src=\"js/jquery-1.5.2.min.js\" type=\"text/javascript\"><\/script>" +
        "<script>" +
            "$(function(){" +
                "$('form[name=\"editDiv" + ID + "\"]').on('submit', function(event){" +
                    "event.preventDefault();" +
                    "var form = this;" +
                    "$.ajax({" +
                        "url: $(form).attr('action')," +
                        "type: \"POST\"," +
                        "data: {divID:$(form.divID).val(), titleN:$(form.titleNew).val(), descN:$(form.descNew).val()}," +
                        "success: function (response) {" +
                            "alert('response');" +
                        "}" +
                    "});" +
                "});" +
            "});" +
        "<\/script>";
    }
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: Why are you inserting jQuery dynamically?

Comment: I have a lot of things with edit buttons and I'd like to be able to edit each one hit save and then let them hit save on the others that's why I don't want to have to reload the page but I guess it might be easier to use php to echo the jquery for each id inside a div and then just hide/show the divs? something I just thought of

Comment: Why do you think it's easier than having the jQuery present in the edit page itself?

Comment: Also, 1.5.2 is outdated now. Consider migrating to 1.8.2 .

Comment: There is no edit page it's just one page but I'm thinking use the php to add a jquery function for each id at the page load so they're all already there. Than I'm thinking create all the forms each in a div and hide them all. Then create the titles and descriptions each in a div and then have a javascript function when edit is pressed that hides the div that holds that rows description and title and then shows it's form

Comment: But is there a reason this current method isn't working?

Comment: I would like to see the HTML and Javacript that gets inserted into the document, after being processed by javascript.

Comment: Why not share jQuery between "ID"s? It's meant to be present once.

Comment: You mean what is placed in the divs? By the above functions?

Comment: Well each form has a different name but I guess I could just pass it the ID and add that to the form name

Comment: i've never found the need to inject javascript by javascript.

Comment: But how would i be able to reuse it because the $('form[name=\"editDiv" + ID + "\"]').on('submit', function(event){ is different for each one

Comment: Script tags can't be inserted that way, and that has to be some of the worst looking code I've seen. Trying to a build an entire site with jQuery and everything inserted purely thru innerHTML is stupidity defined.

Comment: You can create the selector as a string: `$("form[name=" + id + "]")`.

Comment: No need to be rude sorry I'm learning I said I was new to jquery and I'm learning this all on my own

Comment: @adeneo if you attempt to insert script tags, they won't be inserted, but they will be executed.

Comment: @adeneo you should reformulate your comment. While the code does look bad (to us), "stupidity defined" is much too strong.

Comment: Appending script elements, as well as using `eval`, launches the compiler. That's the surest way to kill performance.

Comment: @JanDvorak - My comment is a bit strong, but IMO not strong enough. It's not that the code looks bad (to us), but it's just the concept of building everything by using innerHTML to insert large strings of HTML with script tags, entire ajax functions etc. Any book or tutorial on beginning with javascript will have something like "do not write your html in javascript" within the first few lines. The code above should be deleted completely, and a few hours should be spent on this site or any other site with some code snippets, and those few hours should be enough to get why the above is ludacris.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many cleaner solutions.
I just would hide the form and then display it by clicking edit.
Here is an example with fetching your parents id.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>Test</title>

<style>
    .editForm {
        display:none;
    }
</style>
<script>
</script>

</head>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.edit').click(function() {
        $('.editForm').fadeIn();
    });

    $('a.submit').click(function() {

        // get parents id
        var parentId = $(this).parent().parent().parent().attr('id');

        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "some.php",
          data: { divId: parentId, aName: $('.aName').val() }
        }).done(function( msg ) {
          alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
        });
    });

});
</script>

<body>

<div id="anId">
    <a class="edit">edit</a>
    <form class="editForm">
        <div>
            <input type="text" class="aName" />
            <a href="#" class="button submit">Submit</a>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If i have two divs each with an id how could i reuse the jquery? because only the edit that is clicked should show the form